# substitute url with apache mod proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have configured a new vhost on apache 2.4 and when I tested the configuration all work fine but only one page is not redirected correctly.
the call to the images is done by images.html page :

```
 <ag-iframe agfa-testid="textImageFrame" class="image" reserve-height='{"desktop": 150, "mobile": 200}'
           ng-src="{{viewerUrl}}" onload="onLoad()" force-resize="true">
</ag-iframe>
```

the received code in the browser is like this :

```
<div class="image ng-scope" style="height: 172px;" onload="onLoad()" 
agfa-testid="textImageFrame" src="https://localserver:9251/share/collab?collabSession=263be97d-f16d-491a-a471-bb370a6d9683&amp;type=join&amp;user=username&amp;isInitiator=true" 
    ng-src="https://localserver:9251/share/collab?collabSession=263be97d-f16d-491a-a471-bb370a6d9683&amp;type=join&amp;user=username&amp;isInitiator=true" reserve-height='{"desktop": 150, "mobile": 200}' force-resize="true">
    <iframe id="agIframe" src="https://localserver:9251/share/collab?collabSession=263be97d-f16d-491a-a471-bb370a6d9683&amp;type=join&amp;user=username&amp;isInitiator=true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" ng-src="https://localserver:9251/share/collab?collabSession=263be97d-f16d-491a-a471-bb370a6d9683&amp;type=join&amp;user=username&amp;isInitiator=true">
</iframe>
</div>
```

are there any chance to change all localserver in the response to publicnameserver with substitute, ProxyHTMLURLMap or other mod and proxypass the new url???

I have tryed this :

```
 ProxyHTMLURLMap url(localserver:9251([^)]*)) url(publicnameserver:9251$1) Rihe
```

but in the logs I have this error :

> (Non-HTML content; not inserting proxy-html filter,
>   referer:publicservername/mobile)

may be I have missed some config???

Comment: You already found ProxyHTMLURLMap. Did you try it? What didn't work?

Comment: I have tryed this :  ProxyHTMLURLMap url\(https://localserver:9251([^\)]*)\) url(https://publicnameserver:9251$1) Rihe

Comment: I have tryed this : { ProxyHTMLURLMap url\(https://localserver:9251([^\)]*)\) url(https://publicnameserver:9251$1) Rihe}  but in the logs I have this error : (Non-HTML content; not inserting proxy-html filter, referer: https://publicservername/mobile/) may be I have missed some config???

Comment: Please don't add more information in the comments, it's unreadable here. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct code is :

```
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript application/json
Substitute "s|https:\/\/localserver:9251|https:\/\/publicnameserver:9251|ni"
```

with mod substitute I have replaced the localserver with publicnameserver.

thanks for your help.